# how to use regexp to validate form input javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, forms

I'm beginner at using JavaScript, and I have read documentation of RegExp and went trough couple of examples but I can't to figure it out how to use it properly. 
I have a form which contains 5 input fields. **I need to use RegExp** to validate user input into form. The forbidden values are

( ) { } ' ! # “ \ /

Other characters are allowed but before submitting a form all input field must be entered (no blank/empty fields are allowed).

Input field id="unos_naziv_proizvoda" must contain at least 5 characters and start with capital letter.
Input field id="unos_opis_proizvoda" must contain at least 3 sentences. Sentence starts with a capital letter and end with a dot.
Input field id="unos_datum_proizvodnje" which is date of manufacturing must be in form of dd.mm.yyyy, can't be in the future (must be lower or same as today) and must be type text

Here is HTML code:

```
<form id="forma_prijava" class="forma_novi_proizvod"  action="http://barka.foi.hr/WebDiP/2016/materijali/zadace/ispis_forme.php" method="POST">
            <label for="unos_naziv_proizvoda">Naziv proizvoda</label>
        <input type="text" name="naziv_proizvoda[15]" id="unos_naziv_proizvoda" placeholder="Unesite naziv proizvoda" maxlength="15">
            <label for="unos_opis_proizvoda">Opis proizvoda</label>
        <textarea name="opis_proizvoda" id="unos_opis_proizvoda" placeholder="Ovdje unesite opis proizvoda" rows="50" cols="100"></textarea>
            <label for="unos_datum_proizvodnje">Datum proizvodnje</label>
        <input type="date" name="datum_proizvodnje" id="unos_datum_proizvodnje">
            <label for="unos_vrijeme_proizvodnje">Vrijeme proizvodnje</label>
        <input type="time" name="vrijeme_proizvodnje" id="unos_vrijeme_proizvodnje">
            <label for="unos_kolicina_proizvodnje">Količina proizvodnje</label>
        <input type="number" name="kolicina_proizvodnje" id="unos_kolicina_proizvodnje" placeholder="Unesite količinu proizvodnje" min="1">

            <button type="Submit" value="Submit">Dodaj proizvod</button>
            <button type="Reset" value="Reset">Poništi unos</button>
        </form>
```

Here is js code:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var provjeri = function(){
        var re = new RegExp(/[^(){}'!#"\/]/, g);
        var uzorak = document.getElementById("forma_prijava"); //id of a form //
        var ok = re.test(uzorak.value);
        if(!ok){
            alert("Niste unijeli valjani tekst"); //alert message if it's not valid input //
            return false;
        }
        else{
            alert("OK"); // message if it's valid input //
            return true;
        }
    };
    document.getElementById("forma_prijava").addEventListener("oninput", provjeri);
};
```

I don't know should I use it on a whole form as one unit or on each input field separately because I have different types of input fields (two are text and others are date, time and number). If someone could provide more understandable explanation when providing an example I would appreciate that. :)
Just to point it out once again, **I strictly must use RegExp (pure JavaScript)**, no other libraries or frameworks do not come in mind! 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Form elements don't have a value property...

Comment: You don't need to use Javascript at all to validate input fields on client side. With html5, `input` elements have already a pattern attribute that accept a regex. Also keep in mind that a validation on client side does not suffice (and is more or less useless) since you have to do it systematically on server side.

Comment: As an aside, your pattern `/[^(){}'!#"\/]/` is wrong since it only checks if a string has **one** character that isn't a `(`, `)`, `{`, `}`, `'`, `!`, `#`, `"` or `/`.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I need to use pure JS, that's how the assignment goes. 
"..your pattern /[^(){}'!#"\/]/ is wrong since it only checks if a string has one..." so what would be correct pattern?
I managed to figure it out how regex work and partly make it work but not quite correctly. My regex is checking only first character or how you said if it founds only one that isn't in the pattern, so how can I make it to look trough whole string/sentence and if it found any of forbidden characters it is wrong?
Pls make your post as new answer after Simo so if it works I can accept it as solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use property `pattern` of the input Tag

```
<input type="text" name="country_code" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3}" title="Three letter country code">
```